# генераторы массивов js

Tags: javascript, node.js

Можно ли как на python сделать сделать такой генератор вида `id = [i for i in range(1,15)]`.
У меня есть объект он передает параметры функции send_msg(params)

```
let params = {
    message: message,
    peer_id: id_group[0],
    }
}
```

Мне необходимо чтобы вместо нуля там было итерируемое значение. вида `id_group[i]`. Как это можно реализовать?

Comment: Чтобы каждый раз, когда кто-то берет `params.peer_id`, оно увеличивалось на 1 ? Можно сделать через `Object.defineProperty` - геттер

Comment: Да, а можно пример пожалуйста?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Да собственно можно сделать через тот же генератор.

```
function * range(start, end) {
    while (start < end) {
        yield start++;
    }
}

for (let i of range(1, 15) {
    let params = {
        message: message,
        peer_id: id_group[i],
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понял условия, можно так:

```js
const id_group = [10, 20, 30];
let id_group_counter = 0;

const params = {
  message: 'foo',
  get peer_id() { return id_group[id_group_counter++]; },
};

console.log(JSON.stringify(params));
console.log(JSON.stringify(params));
console.log(JSON.stringify(params));
```